# How can you convert input from a UITextField into a number?

Tags: ios

I have a simple app. The user enters two values threw a text field  and the program adds the values together. Eventually the app will be much more than what it is right now, but i need to know how to convert input from a UITextField object into a number.

This is what I have right now:

```
NSInteger   *intmass = self.accl.integer;
```

I've also tried this an it would just crash my app:

```
intMass = [mass.text integerValue];
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Property 'integer' not found on object type UITextField.
```

Comment: iOS or OS X? I changed your tag to iOS since you mention `UITextField`.

Comment: Say, you probably want your "mass" to be a double value (rather than integer value) so you can have 3.7 kg or 1.2 kg, rather than 3 kg, 1 kg unless the fraction part is of insignificant importance to your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
int myIntValue=[self.textFieldObject.text intValue];
```

This will give you int value. But, if you are trying to save it in NSDictionary or NSArray, it will throw an error.

So, use NSNumber wrapper class to save primitive data type as number objects.

```
NSArray  *a=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myIntValue]];
```

If you want the int value back from a array, we need to use intValue

```
int myIntValue=[[a firstObject] intValue];
```

Note: NSInteger is a int, which is primitive data type not object. You are using it as pointer. Below is the definition of NSInteger.

```
typedef int NSInteger;
```

Comment: Just try and avoid that mixture of dot notation and brackets. `[[self.textFieldObject text] intValue]`.